# Sqoop error when connecting through teradata

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I am unable to execute the `sqoop` command with Teradata.

I am getting this error:

> Error 8017] [SQLState 28000] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.

Sqoop Command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://TDPRODC/LOGMECH=LDAP 
             --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver 
             --username svddssas 
             --password ' ' 
             --table ADW.GST_STST_V 
             --hive-import 
             --hive-table wins.gst_stst_v1 -m 1
```

Comment: Are you passing a whitespace as the password or did you remove it from the command line example? Are you able to use LDAP to connect with this userid by another means (i.e., SQL Assistant, BTEQ, Teradata Studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure, you have permissions with following userId and password in Teradata.

You can check with the below mentioned

```
select * from dbc.logonoff where logdate >= date '2015-10-07'
```

***Note:*** change the date to the execution date.